# How to upload multiple files in micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-rest

```
@Post(value = "/", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA], produces = [APPLICATION_JSON])
fun uploadCompleted(files:List<CompletedFileUpload>,caseId:Int): HttpResponse<String> {
    println("Number of files: ${files.size}")

    /**
     *Implements the rest of the logic 
     */
```

This is my endpoint to upload multiple files. The issue which I am facing is that I am not able to upload multiple files using this endpoint. The println lines gives me "Number of files: 0" outputs. i want to upload multiple files using this endpoint

When I remove the List word and the ankle brackets to upload single file, it works perfectly fine but to upload more than one file the issue is as stated above.

Comment: List won't work you have to use `Publisher`